# What is the grammatical structure of "would that it were"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

It doesn't seem to fit the general templates of English sentences I know. Is this an incomplete sentence? Or is it a shortening of an older phrase now no longer used? What are the subject and the object here?

Comment: It's simply a conversational deletion: "[I] would that it were \[so\]", using the now archaic sense of *would* for *wish* (stemming from *will*, as in "if I had my way", "if I had the power to make it so"). We omit common words all the time, knowing our interlocutor will understand what has been elided.

Comment: That's its origin, but now it's a fixed phrase, idiomatic and archaic, like most of the uses of the English "subjunctive". You're right, it doesn't fit the general templates of English sentences. Idioms don't.

Comment: We now use **"I wish"** in place of "would". That's it.

Comment: @Rathony Not always, as can be seen in constructs such as "I'd rather you didn't". Either way, it's more the origin and internal structure of the phrase that I'm after.

Comment: @biziclop Both "I'd rather you didn't" and "I would that it were" are examples of the subjunctive in English (though there's considerable debate in the  more rarified linguistic circles about what, if anything, can or should be labelled *subjunctive* in English). It was much more common a century ago; its use has and is continuing to fade. The specific motivation for its use in the idiom "would that it were" is that it *ain't*: you're expressing a counterfactual.

Comment: @biziclop OP is asking about "would" rather than "would rather".

Comment: @Rathony I am the OP :)

Comment: @biziclop Nice to know you :)

Comment: An example might help: "Britain is a fair and democratic country" "[I] Would that it were".
So your subject is "I" (but often unvoiced, which might also be to imply that lots of people wish the same as I do - "We" would...). "It" is the object, and refers to whatever the other person said ("Britain" in this case).
And I wish it were what? Well, whatever you claimed it to be.
In effect, "Would that it were" means "No, it isn't, but I wish it was"

Comment: 'wish' may be true, but don't forget the implied 'if', which is more important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Would** is *"archaic"* which means **old and no longer used**. People use "I wish" in place of "(I) would".

I wish I were more handsome. 
I would I were more handsome. (archaic)

It is well explained in Merriam-Webster. Please [click here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would).

**a  archaic:  wished, desired**

**b  archaic:  wish for :  want**

c  (1):  strongly desire :  wish  —often used without a subject and with that in a past or conditional construction

```
(2)—used in auxiliary function with rather or sooner to express preference
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but is not the usual phrase "I would that I ...," not "I would I ...."

Comment: @Jascol: They're related by the grammatical process of "that deletion", and they're both used reasonably often. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+I+were%2C+I+would+that+I+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20I%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20that%20I%20were%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: "were" instead of "was" needs some explanation too.

Comment: @Lembik Yes,  English counterfactual conditionals are expressed with the past subjunctive, hence the use of "were" regardless of person.

Comment: @Lembik What do you need explained? Were is subjunctive. Was is past tense.

Answer (score 3):

It is incorrect to assert that "Would that it were" is "no longer used". It is used and understood not infrequently in certain circles, particularly among the literate intelligentsia.

And regardless of its origins as "[I] would that it were [so]", the phrase "Would that it were" de-emphasizes the subject to simply express the wish, much like "Long live the king!" and other subjunctive wishes that omit the subject.

Comment: Just a clarification: there was never any assertion that "would that it were" is no longer used.